# How can I find code which is never used at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

Take the following example:
A complex condition populates a variable printingStatus and it's really time demanding to discover if it happens. But it would be enough to monitor all the clients in the production environment to know if this code is used or not.

Is there any tool to implement this kind of Dynamic Code Analysis?

```
if (isOrdinatoPerCampionato && typeTable == 2
                && RowIndex > 0 && (!isNotUltimaRiga || isRigaDataMainHeader)
                && Condizione(rigaPrecedente, tournamentStatisticInfo, TournamentPrintingData))
            {
                printingStatus = PrintingStatus.Statistics;
                TournamentPrintingData.Row = rigaPrecedente;
            }
```

Comment: It's called a profiler that produces code coverage results. Automating the generation and collecting of such reports across machines is a bit involved, though. You're almost certainly better off adding in custom logging (either with a file or an ETW event) if you're interested in whether *particular* conditions that you know to be expensive get exercised.

Comment: Solving this in general is equivalent to The Halting Problem. (Eg. despite gathering a huge amount of data it is only the next data input that exercises some code…)

Comment: Code coverage is the way to go, for a pre-static analysis you can use the tool ndepend that comes with several rules dedicated to dead code detection. https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html

Comment: Interestingly enough, we foster having classes 100% covered by tests and having rules to check for this 100% coverage. This way when suddenly the class is not 100% covered by tests, an issue is reported and can be investigated. Typically a significant problem is around when suddenly there is a hole in 100% coverage.